# how to get the sum of particular columns and total number of rows in a table in mysql

Tags: mysql

It's very simple but couldn't figure it out.

here is my table

```
a     b
---------
s1    prod
s2    prod
s3    dev
s4    prod
s5    dev
```

What I am expecting is as follows

```
Environment  count
prod         3
dev          2
total        5
```

So along with the group by Environment field also looking for a total of count.

Comment: Hint: `SELECT` and then `GROUP BY`

Comment: And then `WITH ROLLUP`

Comment: Could you elaborate, please

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

```
 SELECT b AS Environment, COUNT(a) AS COUNT FROM <tablename> GROUP BY b UNION SELECT 'total' AS Environment, COUNT(a) AS COUNT FROM <tablename>;
```

It may help you

Comment: _It just gives them out put with out the last line (mentioned my expected results) which is total of all group by numbers__